# Optimizing appengine entity key usage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Should I care about locality of entities on the Google App Engine datastore?
Should I use custom entity key names for that?

For example, I could use **"$article_uuid,$comment_id"** as the key name of a Comment entity.
Will it improve the speed of fetching all comments for an article?
Or is it better to use shorter keys?

Is it a good practice to use the key in this way?
I could use the **"$article_uuid,$comment_id"** key name also instead of an index:

```
def get_comments(article_uuid, limit=1000):
    key_prefix=db.Key.from_path('Comment', article_uuid)
    q = Comment.gql("where __key__ > :key_prefix and __key__ < :range_end",
        key_prefix=key_prefix, range_end=key_prefix+chr(ord(',')+1))
    return q.fetch(limit)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locality of your data will be improved with your `key_name` scheme ([ref, see slide 40](http://www.chariotsolutions.com/slides/pdfs/ete2009-GoogleUndertheCoversApp.pdf)) - since your `key_name` is prefixed with the corresponding article's ID, comments for a given article should be stored near each other.

The `key_name` you proposed doesn't seem like it would be too long.  I don't think you'll see too much difference between that and shorter keys in terms of storage space or serialization/deserialization time.  I expect that the size of the `Comment` entity will be dominated by the rest of the entity.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't seem to dig up a copy of either a transcript or a video of that presentation.  If you're interested in reading more, there are a lot of good articles [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/).

Comment: Yes, entities with common prefixes are likely to end up on the same tablet - but that doesn't mean they'll be loaded any faster. Entities on different tablets are likely to be on different tabletservers, and so will be loaded in parallel from each server.